# Condition to send error message (JSON, SQL)

Tags: javascript, json

First sorry for my english, I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I've made a function in order to return a table created with a json based on sql query values inside this json.

Sometimes, the sql query is wrong and I can't get into my json.
That's why I have a variable named `test` which is created inside the `$.getJSON`.

With a `if`, I check if test is defined or not. If it is not, I send an alert to the user :

`if(typeof test == "undefined"){
     $('#loading').hide();
     alert("Erreur dans la requete, veuillez modifier vos filtres."); //Error !
     return;
  }`

My problem is that even if my query is correct, I still get my error message. I don't know why because if I print `test` with a `console.log(test)`, I get 1 as it is in the code...

Here is my entire function if you want to take a look :

```
function get_values(){ //Fonction permettant la creation du tableau de resultats

  $('#loading').show();

  $("table#mon_tableau").removeClass("hidden");

  var myjson = "http://******/get_json_test.php?callback=?";
  $('.filter').each(function(i, obj){
     var input = $(obj).find("input")[0];
     myjson += '&'+input.name+'=' + input.value;
  });

  $('.display').each(function(i,obj){
     myjson += '&'+$(obj).attr('table')+'|'+$(obj).attr('titre')+'';
  });

  console.log(myjson);

  $.getJSON(myjson, function(data){
     var titre_colindex = 0;
     var test = 1;
        if(data.length != 0){
           newRow = document.getElementById('mon_tableau').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertRow(-1);
              $.each(data[0], function(index, valeur){ //Pour chaque colonne
                 newCell = newRow.insertCell(titre_colindex);
                 newCell.innerHTML = index;
                 titre_colindex+=1;
              });

              $.each(data, function(i,ti){
                 var newRow;
                 var newCell;
                    newRow = document.getElementById('mon_tableau').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertRow(-1);
                    //newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                    //newCell.innerHTML = ti.TI;

                 var i_colindex=0;
                 $.each(ti, function(index, valeur){
                    //if(index != "TI"){
                       newCell = newRow.insertCell(i_colindex);
                       newCell.innerHTML = valeur;
                       i_colindex+=1;
                    //}
                 });
              }); //End each
           console.log(erreur);
           $('#loading').hide();
           alert("Il y a " + data.length + " resultats");
        }
        else{
           $('#loading').hide();
           $("table#mon_tableau").addClass("hidden");
           alert("Il n'y a aucun resultat...");
        }
  console.log(test);
  }); //End getJSON

  if(typeof test == "undefined"){
     $('#loading').hide();
     alert("Erreur dans la requete, veuillez modifier vos filtres.");
     return;
  }
  console.log(test);
} //End getvalues
```

Comment: Where do you have 'console.log(test)'?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I deleted it, it's at the end of my .getJSON and at the end of my function, for both I get 1, check my edit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getJSON` is an asynchronous call.  It will execute the call, then immediately execute your if statement **before** the data has been returned, which is why it's always undefined.  Instead, you would want to include this if statement in the success or failure routine.

Ideally, you don't even need the test variable, as you can leverage the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) call since it returns a promise, with `.done` (sucess) and `fail` (error) routines.  Your code would be changed to something like this:

```
$.getJSON(myjson).done(function(data){
    // all your success code here
}).fail(function() (
    // your failure code here
});
```